# Hyperlinks in a cloacked website

Tags: html, hyperlink, forwarding

I have a website which is hosted via my providers webhosting.
I have bought another domainname and forwarded my current website to it.
The technique it uses is cloacking, so my old website is a frame in my new domain.
Everything works perfectly but when I click a hyperlink that goes outside the website (**e.g. facebook page**), the page won't show.
I have the following error in my Google Chrome console:

Refused to display Hyperlink in a frame because it set `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY`.
Any link, tutorial help  will be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it like that – bad for SEO, usability and things like this. There isn't any solution other than either use a really old browser or don't use the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Frame-Options` is submitted by pages if they don't want to be displayed in `frame` or `iframe` (see [mdn: The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options))

The message tells you that Facebook tells the browser, that it does not want to be displayed in a frame. To solve this problem you need to set the `target` attribute for these links  to `_top` or `_parent`. But be award that the user could prevent these options by browser extensions.

If you plan to use the second domain instead of the first one you should think over doing a `301` redirect. What you should avoid is to find a solution that displays the same content (without `iframe`) on both domains, because of double content.